# QGIS 3.20 cannot launch on desktop after changing the environmental variable

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, installation, conda

I installed QGIS 3.20 and changed the environmental variable to append `PYTHONHOME` to a miniconda environment.

After that, I cannot launch QGIS desktop again. The welcome picture flashes, and after "setting up UI", no desktop pops up. I guess something wrong when load PyQt5 dlls. Anyone has face the same issue before?

Comment: Unset your PYTHONHOME. Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: I am using Windows. I've remove PYTHONHOME and had uninstall and reinstall several time QGIS. I also remove miniconda and the virtual env. However, QGIS still does not launch. It flash QGIS 3.20 Odense and then disappear. No QGIS desktop pops out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was resolved by resetting the profile:

```
mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles ~/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles_bk
```

Source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Mac-Packager

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, delete the config directory.

Windows:

%LocalAppData%\QGIS

%AppData%\QGIS

Linux:

/home/USERNAME/.local/share/QGIS

Macintosh:

/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS